# Swift How to take a photo and save with same button

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avcapture

I am a beginner.
I have a question....
How can I write the code so that every time the photo is snap it will be saved to the photo gallery. I just want to logic that if man press the taking a photo button, right save the photo and if i want to see the photo, i have to go to gallery. thanks for reading me.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    var backCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
    var frontCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
    var currentCamera: AVCaptureDevice?

    var photoOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput?

    var cameraPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?

    var image: UIImage?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupCaptureSession()
        setupDevice()
        setupInputOutput()
        setupPreviewLayer()
        startRunningCaptureSession()

    }

    func setupCaptureSession(){
        captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo

    }
    func setupDevice(){
        let deviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: AVCaptureDevice.Position.unspecified)
        let device = deviceDiscoverySession.devices

        for device in device {
            if device.position == AVCaptureDevice.Position.back {
                backCamera = device
            } else if device.position == AVCaptureDevice.Position.front {
                frontCamera = device
            }
             currentCamera = backCamera
        }

    }
    func setupInputOutput(){
        do {
            let captureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: currentCamera!)
            captureSession.addInput(captureDeviceInput)
            photoOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
            photoOutput?.setPreparedPhotoSettingsArray([AVCapturePhotoSettings(format: [AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecType.jpeg])], completionHandler: nil)
            captureSession.addOutput(photoOutput!)

        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

    }
    func setupPreviewLayer(){
        cameraPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        cameraPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        cameraPreviewLayer?.connection?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
        cameraPreviewLayer?.frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.layer.insertSublayer(cameraPreviewLayer!, at: 0)

    }
    func startRunningCaptureSession(){

        captureSession.startRunning()
    }


    @IBAction func cameraButton_TouchIpInside(_ sender: Any) {
        let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
        photoOutput?.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)
      // performSegue(withIdentifier: "showPhoto_Segue", sender: nil)
    }



    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showPhoto_Segue" {
            let previewVC = segue.destination as! PreviewViewController
            previewVC.image = self.image
        }
    }
}

    extension ViewController: AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {
    func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
        if let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation() {
            print(imageData)
            image = UIImage(data: imageData)
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "showPhoto_Segue", sender: nil)
        }
    }
} // this is main ViewController.


 import UIKit

class PreviewViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var photo: UIImageView!
    var image: UIImage!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        photo.image = self.image

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func cancelButton_TouchUpInside(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    @IBAction func saveButton_YouvhUpInside(_ sender: Any) {

        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

} // this is second ViewController
```

Comment: What's your problem here?

Comment: I want the same button that works takeing photos and saving them at the same time.  :(.....